# How do I align text that span over multiple lines to after the punctuation in a markdown unordered list in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The current behavior as follow:

```
- List item 1
  - List item 1.1 that span over
  multiple line
- List item 2
```

I want it to look like this:

```
- List item 1
  - List item 1.1 that span over
    multiple lines
- List item 2
```

The main reason I want to improve this is readability. I already searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer to that, I hope someone will be able to help me, if it's even possible.

I tried to search in google and looked at the settings of visual studio code but I couldn't find any solution. Referring to the textMateRules didn't help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution; adding the following lines to the settings.json file will change the wrapping indent to what I described above.

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 1,
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "deepIndent"
}
```